# Can't two ListItem objects have same value property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem

My Code looks like

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="100">A</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="100">B</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Now when I try to select B, It by default selects A always. B is never selected. What is the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: Do you need to have the same Value for two items?

Answer (score 4):

The `<asp:ListBox>` renders as a [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) with `<option>`s in HTML. The value is persisted across postbacks, not the text. So it can't tell which value you wanted when there are multiple options with the same value, so it assumed the first. It's best practice to use unique option values.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use different values for 2 or more items. No two items can have the same values.

Set `AutoPostBack="True"` and you'll find that no matter how many items you add in the `ListBox`, it will always select the `0th` index of that particular value.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="101">D</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="100">A</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="100">B</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="102">E</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="100">C</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Like, selecting `B` or `C` will always select `A`; where `A` being the `0th` index for that particular value `100`.